# NodeJS - How to insert an element in a HTML document using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to use NodeJS to modify an external HTML file (which is located in the same directory). In my index.js file I write:

```
fs.readFile('index.html', (err,html)=>{
  if(err){
     throw err;
  }

html.body.innerHTML += '<div id = "asdf"></div>';

});
```

As index.html is a valid document. But it doesn't look to be reading it properly, as I get as an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined".

I guess that html is not getting anything as body.

How can I do changes in HTML using JavaScript?

Comment: Thats not how it works. In your case it is just a string. Try to parse it with, for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

Comment: Where `html.body` are defined? `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` error is already saying it

Comment: @AbhishekPandey my HTML document looks like this:

`<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Node JS</h1>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri thanks, it looks interesting. I will try to go throughout that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example using [node-html-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser)

HTML file

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="fist">yolo</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the nodejs

```
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('node-html-parser').parse;

fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', (err,html)=>{
   if(err){
      throw err;
   }

   const root = parse(html);

   const body = root.querySelector('body');
   //body.set_content('<div id = "asdf"></div>');
   body.appendChild('<div id = "asdf"></div>');

   console.log(root.toString()); // This you can write back to file!
 });
```

There might be better solutions than node-html-parser, considering the amount of downloads. For example, [htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) has much more downloads, but it also looks more complex :)

Comment: I had to change the second argument of 'fs.readFile' to `utf8`, but it looks great. Thank you so much! Also, html parser looks to be helpful for more complex things to do.

Answer (score 1):

In order to manipulate an html file the way you'd be able to in a browser, you'll first need to parse it.

Perhaps [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) can be of use? (Or if a few milliseconds of parsing are not a concern and you want some more functionality, the [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) package is very popular too.)

Answer (score -1):

innerHTML is a function provided after DOM parsing. Here you are using a string, so you can either use a DOM parser to create the structure or you can just use regex to isolate the part you want to replace and append the text.

```
html.replace("</body>",'<div id = "asdf"></div></body>');
```

Comment: That's right, but my main problem now is that I'm not getting the `HTML` document in the `html`variable. Now I'm getting `TypeError: html.replace is not a function`.

Comment: are you sure the path is right ?
I mean, it is basic fileread, once you have the string in the callback, it should be easy. What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: In your case `readFile` returns a `Buffer`. Read the file as `fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', (err, html) => { ... })` and it will work. But doing this with RegExes is fragile, don't do it and use a parser!