# how to add child node using node-html-parser?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-parsing

I'm trying to add a child node using `node-html-parser` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58265036)

my html file looks like this:

```
...

 <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
   ...
 </tbody>
```

and node.js app:

```
const parse = require('node-html-parser').parse;

...

  const doc = parse(fs.readFileSync('./myfile.html','utf8'));
  doc.querySelector("tbody").appendChild("<tr></tr>");
```

but it's giving an error:

> ```
> Cannot create property 'parentNode' on string '<tr></tr>'
> ```

Comment: can you add your HTML, It seems the parsing is an issue. Have you validated the HTML?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara the html is too big to add here so I added the key part, but I have validated it

Comment: This error comes when you try to add something to a string. It means the parsing is not done properly. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510186/cannot-create-property-on-string).